# Which of the averaging of the AUC-ROC / AUC-PR on scikit-learn are usually used on papers when comparing classifiers

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics

I've read lots of paper with classification focus and most of them said that using AUC-PR is better when working with an imbalanced problem .. such as this quotes from [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jdavis/davisgoadrichcamera2.pdf):

> A large number change in the number of false positives can lead to a small change in the false positive rate used in ROC analysis. Precision, on the other hand, by comparing false positives to true positives rather than true negatives, captures the effect of the large number of negative examples on the algorithm's performance.

However, I am not sure which averaging in scikit-learn represent the calculation such paper use .. is it the macro averaging or the weighted ?

Answer (score 0):

That is a good question. For a *binary* problem setup, class imbalance does not affect your AUC score (which is why AUC is often a preferred metric).

For a multiclass setup it does, however, it should be clearly specified in the paper which kind of metric they use. The default implementation in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html) is *macro* averaging; I presume it is their default for a reason.

Comment: By AUC do you refer to the AUC-ROC or AUC-PR or the imbalance will not affect both of them ?

Comment: I meant both, but according to this [paper](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jdavis/davisgoadrichcamera2.pdf), the AUC-PR is even more able to deal with imbalanced class distributions.